# Convert IANA time zone to int in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my Posgresql database I have column which have value time zone in IANA format as text. I am able to take this value and convert to int in query?

For example value in my column `America/New_York` and I need get value `-4/5` in my script.

I starting with take my value from database but don't know what to do with that next.

```
Select settings.time_zone into time_z from time_zone where id = 1
```

Is it possible?

Comment: 1) This `-4/5` is a string not an integer. 2) What is this `Select settings.time_zone into time_z from time_zone where id = 1` supposed to be doing? [Select into](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) creates a new table is that what you are trying to do? Or is this part of a `plpgsql` function where `select into` means something else? **ADD answers AS TEXT as update to question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work well with every time zone, because there are time zones that are not offset by whole hours. To get the offset as an `interval`, you can use

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2000-01-01 00:00:00+00'
          AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
     - TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 00:00:00';

 ?column?  
═══════════
 -05:00:00
(1 row)
```

If you are sure you will never deal with time zones that don't have an offset in whole hours, you can get an integer by extracting the number of hours:

```
SELECT CAST (
          EXTRACT (
             hours FROM
                TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2000-01-01 00:00:00+00'
                   AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
              - TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
          ) AS integer
       );

 cast 
══════
   -5
(1 row)
```

Instead of the string literal `'America/New_York'`, you can use any expression.

Note that the date you choose (2000-01-01 in my example) matters. For one, you will get a different result if the time zone has daylight savings time, and you choose a day in summer, and then the time zone might have been different in 2000. So choose wisely.

Comment: And obviously the amount will change by 1 hour in locations that operate some sort of DST depending on the time of year you provide in your query.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Good point, that could be a problem. I'll add it to the answer.